# ExceptionIgnored error: SIGALRM Timeout handler

Tags: python, exception

I made a custom timeout handler using the SIGALRM signal but very rarely I get an error saying that TimeoutException was 'ignored'.

**Timeout handler code:**

```
def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutException

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)


camera_stream = ThreadedCamera() # Separate Thread updating image
while True:
    try:
        while True:
            signal.alarm(5) # start 5s timer
            send_image(camera_stream.image) # function is blocked if it doesnt finish within 5 seconds
            signal.alarm(0) # end timer
    except TimeoutException:
        print("timeout")
        time.sleep(5)
```

**Error:**

```
Exception ignored in: <function Context.__del__ at 0x7f93e
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "zmq/sugar/context.py", line 71, in __del__
File "zmq/sugar/context.py", line 190, in term
File "zmq/backend/cython/context.pyx", line 82, in zmq.backend.cyt
File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 13, in zmq.backend.cyt
File "camera_client.py", line 22, in timeout_handler
__main__.TimeoutException:
```

It seems like my try/except statement should catch the TimeouteException considering the alarm is cancelled before I exit the try/except.
Is it possible that the camera in the separate thread is somehow catching this error?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is that `function()` doing something with threads/processes itself? I'm asking because there seems to be some sort of error in a `__del__` overriden function. That function is called when the garbage collector runs. Which makes me think that _something_ is happening in between when your `function()` ends and `signal.alarm(0)` is called. Like... the garbage collector attempts to clean something that is not used anymore after `function()` is completed but before `signal.alarm(0)` is called. (Mind you: I might be utterly wrong about this...)

Comment: I forgot to specify in the question, but the while loop is all inside of a separate thread. I dont believe function() creates another thread but it is sending an image over a network socket

Comment: Ah. Pretty sure that's what it is then. Signals are handled by (thrown to) the main thread (https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signals-and-threads ). So what could very well be happening (maybe? this is confusing to me too XD) is that your try/except is happening in a "child" thread. Which is not the thread that will receive the exception.

Comment: Wait I just realized I'm not creating a separate thread here (got mixed up with another program)